# Passing Nullable Integer (int? SomeValue = NULL) As Parameter To Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that would take 4 paramters. These 4 paramters dictate how the returned table will look like.

`@C_ID` parameter is always numeric. `@U_ID` and `@P_ID` values can contain a valid numeric value, or can be (or should be) passed as `NULL` so `WHERE` conditions either execute or not.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetData]
    @C_ID integer,
    @U_ID integer = Null,
    @P_ID integer = Null,
    @SortIndex integer = 1
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT
        ID, P_ID, U_Name, P_Name, 
        FORMAT(Date_When, 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt')
    FROM 
        SomeTable
    WHERE 
        C_ID = @C_ID 
        AND (@P_ID IS NULL OR P_ID = @P_ID) 
        AND (@U_ID IS NULL OR U_ID = @U_ID)
   ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN @SortIndex = 1 THEN -ID 
             ELSE ID 
        END ASC
END
```

On SQL Server 2014 the following executions work fine without any errors:

```
exec GetData '15', null, null, '1';
exec GetData '15', '1', null, '1';
exec GetData '15', null, '1', '1';
exec GetData '15', '1', '1', '1';
...
```

However on C# side the following code fails to execute:

```
int? SomeValue = null;
Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("exec GetData '15'," + SomeValue + ",null,'1';", Connection);
Adapter.Fill(Data);
```

which gives me an error

> Incorrect syntax near ','.

If I change the `SomeValue` variable to 1, it works perfectly fine.

`DBNull.Value` and simply leaving the parameter as ' ' do not work either.

So the question would be: how would I (if it is possible) be able to pass nullable integer to SQL given that it can be both null and a valid number?

Comment: [Please do not construct SQL queries with concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683).

Comment: As for the formal answer to your question, this is because `SomeValue `, being `null`, inserts an empty string into the resulting string, which results in two subsequent commas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do something along those lines:

```
Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

//con is an open SQLConnection
var cmd = new SQLCommand("GetData", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@C_ID", 15));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@U_ID", SomeValue ?? DBNull.Value));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@P_ID", SomeValue ?? DBNull.Value));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SortIndex", 1));
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
Adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
Adapter.Fill(Data);
```

The `??` is called the null-coalescing operator and checks if `SomeValue` is null. If so, the value behind the ?? is used - in your case `DBNull.Value`.

And as GSerg already pointed out, always keep Little Bobby Tables in the back of your head.

Edit: [Null-coalescing reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173224.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't think I've encountered ?? operator before.

Comment: Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'System.DBNull'
If I change it to SomeValue ?? (object)DBNull.Value I get : ExecuteReader: CommandText property has not been initialized

Comment: Oh, I forgot to pass a valid connection into the SQLCommand. You need to do this: `var cmd = new SQLCommand("GetData", con);` where `con` is an open `SQLConnection`. This plus casting DBNull.Value to object, like you already did, should do the trick.

Comment: It wont work until you cast integer to object.
("@CategoryID", (object)id ?? DBNull.Value)

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried something like below?

```
SomeValue ?? "null"
```